# Is there way to get PostgreSQL service name?

Tags: c#, windows, npgsql

Is there way to get PostgreSQL service name?

I mean something like `SELECT @@SERVICENAME` as in MS SQL Server. Or maybe it is declared in one of config files?

It's called Service ID:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the "servicename" in SQL Server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180056.aspx) says `MSSQLSERVER`

Comment: I don't think there is a corresponding concept in Postgres.

Comment: Ok, I got it. How I can get name of service in the service control manager from db configs or the database itself?

Comment: That is the name of the Windows service. That information is e.g. not available when being connected to a Linux server (and I doubt it's available when being connected to a Postgres instance running on a different computer other then where pgAdmin is running).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specified OS. It's applicable for only Windows OS.

Comment: Do you mean 'SHOW ALL' ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found something on my windows services, related to postgresql windows service
the service name appears to be "pg_ctl.exe"

i got some prints bellow

PostgreSQL Service Name:
[image]

[image]